# яндекс карта (vue-yandex-maps) не появляется, высота 0

Tags: vue.js, яндекс-карты

Всем привет.
Не могу вывести яндекс карту. Пишу spa на vue через webpack (однофайловые компоненты).

Подключила библиотеку 'vue-yandex-maps' - https://vue-yandex-maps.github.io/guide/

Все делала по инструкции. По примерам. Причем, если проверить через инструменты разработчика chrome - карта там формируется, но высота нескольких ее элементов = 0px.

В API яндекс карт нашла:
[image: сводка из апи яндекс карт]

Как я понимаю, карта должна быть инициализирована после рендеринга приложения.

Я во vue новичок и не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать через библиотеку.

Вот код моего компонента Geography.vue :

```html
<template>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <h2>география</h2>

        <div class="map-box">
            <yandex-map ymap-class="ymapbox" :coords="coords" :zoom="11" :controls="controls" :scroll-zoom="scrollZoom">
                <ymap-marker 
                    marker-type="placemark"
                    :coords="[54.7, 39.7]"
                    :markerId="1"
                    hint-content="Hint content 1"
                    :balloon="{header: 'header', body: 'body', footer: 'footer'}"
                    :icon="{color: 'green', glyph: 'cinema'}"
                    />
                <ymap-marker 
                    marker-type="placemark"
                    :coords="[54.6, 39.8]"
                    :markerId="2"
                    hint-content="Hint content 1"
                    :balloon="{header: 'header', body: 'body', footer: 'footer'}"
                    :icon="{color: 'green', glyph: 'cinema'}"
                    />
            </yandex-map>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Geography',
        data () {
            return {
                coords: [54.6, 39.8],
                controls: ['fullscreenControl', 'searchControl', 'zoomControl'],
                scrollZoom: false
            }
        },
        // methods: {
            // yaMapInit() { // methods()
                // this.SuggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView(this.geoInput, {
                    // provider: this.provider,
                    // boundedBy: this.bounds[this.brandCode]
            // });
        // },
        // mounted() {
            // ymaps.ready(this.yaMapInit());
        // }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .map-box, .ymap-container, .ymapbox, ymaps {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 600px;
    }
</style>
```

Подключение плагина делала глобально в main.js :

```html
import Vue from 'vue'

import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/ru-RU'
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })
// Vue.config.productionTip = false

import router from './router'
Vue.use(router)

import YmapPlugin from 'vue-yandex-maps'
const settings = {
  apiKey: '77a5e6ea-6171-44e6-bdac-228f66072a3e',
  lang: 'ru_RU',
  coordorder: 'latlong',
  version: '2.1'
}
Vue.use(YmapPlugin, settings)


import App from './App.vue'


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ElementUI,
  router,
  YmapPlugin,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <section class="wrapper">
        <h2>география</h2>
        <yandex-map ymap-class="map-box" :coords="coords" :zoom="11" :controls="controls" :scroll-zoom="scrollZoom">
            <ymap-marker 
                marker-type="placemark"
                :coords="[54.7, 39.7]"
                :markerId="1"
                hint-content="Hint content 1"
                :balloon="{header: 'header', body: 'body', footer: 'footer'}"
                :icon="{color: 'green', glyph: 'cinema'}"
                />
            <ymap-marker 
                marker-type="placemark"
                :coords="[54.6, 39.8]"
                :markerId="2"
                hint-content="Hint content 1"
                :balloon="{header: 'header', body: 'body', footer: 'footer'}"
                :icon="{color: 'green', glyph: 'cinema'}"
                />
        </yandex-map>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Geography',
        data () {
            return {
                coords: [54.6, 39.8],
                controls: ['fullscreenControl', 'searchControl', 'zoomControl'],
                scrollZoom: false
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .map-box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>
```